Spring Webflux / Netty - Application getting spikes of ReadTimeoutException
I'm using Spring Webflux's WebClient, which under the hood uses Netty. I have an application that needs to make a POST call and perform some business logic with a specified response time. Most of the time the application runs fine, but over an extended period the application will see spikes of io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException. The server and client has plenty of CPU and Memory available.
Ideally a single application instance can handle 50-100 TPS at least. But with how basic the example code I'd expect a few hundred TPS.
Here's a GitHub repo that may be able to replicate the problem depending on your computer specs. See README for instructions.
https://github.com/LoganDev99/NettyReadTimeoutException
WebClient Configuration
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
                .create()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 50)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(300));

        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
    }

Rest Controller
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    @PostMapping
    public Mono<MyResponse> myEndpoint(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        return webClient.post()
                .uri("http://localhost:8181/mock")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .bodyValue(myRequest)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(MyResponse.class)
                .flatMap(myResponse -> {
                    final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                    log.info("Duration: {}ms", endTime);
                    // Business Logic
                    return  Mono.just(MyResponse.builder()
                                    .id(myResponse.getId())
                            .build());
                }).timeout(Duration.ofMillis(600))
                .doOnError(e -> log.error(e.getCause().getMessage()));
    }
}

Here's a fuller log incase the thread groups help reveal something.
2024-07-22T20:31:22.644-04:00 ERROR 16624 --- [webfluxerror] [io-8080-exec-13] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException] with root cause

io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null

2024-07-22T20:31:22.646-04:00  WARN 16624 --- [webfluxerror] [ctor-http-nio-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [9b86be2d-1, L:/127.0.0.1:49763 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8181] The connection observed an error


have you confirmed whether or not the downstream is responding slower during the periods in which you observe timeouts?
